# Django Count in Annotate and Subquery are much slower than simply iterating over my items and filtering individualy

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to count how many documents per project (among other things) have been registered, Registered also holds other values like DateTime and User (just a disclosure they are unrelated to my issue).

Iterating through a list and querying ~54 times ends up being much faster than Annotate or Subquery (13 vs 27 seconds)

I have 4 tables  which go like this *Project* -> *Batch* -> *Document* -> *Registered*. Right now we have **54** *Projects*, **20478** *Batches*, **3231095** *Documents* and **312498** *Registered*.

The timings listed below are for the entire view, not just the bits represented, but you can have an idea on their impact...

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(completion_date__isnull=True)

# "Fast", takes around 13.5 seconds to evaluate
for project in list(projects.values('id')):
    count = Document.objects.filter(batch__project_id=project['id], registered__isnull=False)
    
# Both methods below are much slower, taking around 27 seconds to evaluate

# Simple annotation
projects = projects.annotate(count=Count('batches__documents', filter=Q(batches__documents__registered__isnull=False), distinct=True))

# An attempt to simulate the first list iteration query without multiple db hits, ends up exactly as slow as annotate
subq_registered = Document.objects.filter(batch__project_id=OuterRef('id'), registered__isnull=False).annotate(count=Func(F('id'), function='Count')).values('count')
projects = projects.annotate(count=Subquery(subq_registered))
```

I expected Subquery to be faster than my first method, as it would mimic it, but its just as slow as simple count + annotation.

Is there something I can do to speed any of my methods up? perhaps adding a *Project* foreign key to *Document*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `GROUP BY` functionality here like this:

```
 Document.objects.filter(batch__project__completion_date__isnull=True).values('batch__project').annotate(doc_count= Count('pk')).values('batch__project','doc_count')
```

More information on [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

Regarding the performance issue, there is no straight answer on why the performance is slow. Because (at least) the simple annotation makes single DB call, where others make more DB hits. There could be an issue with Database itself, maybe it has indexing issues (which needs debugging). I would recommend looking into this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-overuse-contains-count-and-exists) regarding how to debug and optimize database related issues.

Comment: With GROUP BY total time went down from 13.5s to 10s, I removed all the mentioned code and 8.5s is how long it takes for the other stuff in the view to process. I'll try using GROUP BY on the rest in a similar manner. I'll also attempt to do some maitenance on the Database later, thank you!